# Title and Occupation Correlation Model

Tags: correlation, python, text-mining, spark-mllib

I have a large set of data that contains both a person's title (e.g., "CEO", "Bank Teller", "Fireman", etc.). and occupation codes (e.g, "A1": Managerial, "A2": Laborer, etc.).  I need to build an algorithm that will tell me the most likely occupation code given a new title, but I can't expect the new title to match any existing title, at least not exactly.  Ideally, I would be able to score each new title to each occupation code, such as ("Policeman" = "A5"; score: .89).  The difficulty lies in the fact that people may have complicated titles that are not in my existing data set ("Assistant Director to the Manager of ...").
I figure I need to create a matrix dictionary from my existing titles, and then calculate the correlation to the occupation code?  But then how do I apply this to new values?
I'm working in Python and Spark if that makes a difference.